# low marginal and high conditional R2 for mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, r-squared

I have a suspicious output in my linear mixed model lmer() (lmer package), where I have marginal r2 of 0.08 and conditional of 0.8.

I am not surprised by the low marginal r2, however, I am puzzled about the conditional. I have a dataset of 2137 observations, with multiple measures per respondent (total independent n = 909). Can this "detailed" grouping be a reason for such a high conditional r2?

```
MM_WTP = lmer(z_WTP ~ z_current + Support + Bio_cont + CH_importance + Easy_recogn + Frequency + (1|ID), data = z_all_SEM, REML = F)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']

Formula: transformed_WTP ~ transformed_price + Support + Bio_cont + CH_importance +      Easy_recogn + Frequency + (1 | ID)

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4736.2   4787.2  -2359.1   4718.2     2128 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9528 -0.4151  0.0095  0.4066  4.4646 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.7067   0.8407  
 Residual             0.2193   0.4683  
Number of obs: 2137, groups:  ID, 909

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -1.519e+00  1.841e-01  1.116e+03  -8.254 4.30e-16 ***
transformed_price  6.307e-02  1.557e-02  1.677e+03   4.051 5.33e-05 ***
Support            2.607e-01  3.252e-02  9.101e+02   8.015 3.37e-15 ***
Bio_cont           1.944e-02  2.572e-02  1.998e+03   0.756   0.4499    
CH_importance      4.619e-02  1.939e-02  2.051e+03   2.382   0.0173 *  
Easy_recogn        9.502e-03  1.976e-02  2.046e+03   0.481   0.6306    
Frequency         -2.850e-03  1.130e-02  1.793e+03  -0.252   0.8009    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) trnsf_ Supprt Bi_cnt CH_mpr Esy_rc
trnsfrmd_pr  0.036                                   
Support     -0.874 -0.029                            
Bio_cont     0.124 -0.153 -0.036                     
CH_importnc -0.142 -0.056 -0.097 -0.079              
Easy_recogn -0.229  0.009 -0.023 -0.070 -0.334       
Frequency   -0.128  0.024  0.028 -0.001 -0.154 -0.083


> r2_nakagawa(MM_WTP)
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.781
     Marginal R2: 0.076
```

Comment: How are you calculating R-squared for a mixed model?

Comment: I am using r2 Nakagawa from performance package in R.

Comment: Thanks, Elena. Can you post the `lmer` sytanx and output for your model? it would help to know the complexity of the random effects you are estimating.

Comment: Hi Erik. Sorry, I should have put once I published the question. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2_nakagawa.html) for `r2_nakagawa`,

> The marginal r-squared considers only the variance of the fixed
>   effects, while the conditional r-squared takes both the fixed and
>   random effects into account.

Looking at the random effect variances of your model, you have a large proportion of your outcome variation at the ID level - .71 (ID) out of .93 (ID+Residual). This suggests to me that ID is sucking up a lot of the outcome variance and I would suspect that this is the reason the conditional $R^2$ is so much larger than the marginal $R^2$. I don't know the  level at which your predictors are measured, but you can get a sense of how much ID explains outcome variation by running a simple `lm` model as such:

`lmmod <-  lm(z_WTP ~ 1 + as.factor(ID), data=z_all_SEM)`

My bet is that this model with just dummy variables for ID and no other predictors will give a large $R^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! You are right, testing ID in an lm gives 77% of explained variance. I am using ID as a random effect, to solve the observation dependency problem, and it is logical in this case that a respondent tends to give similar responses. But is such a difference is to be concerned of for the model's output, or it would be ok to mention the difference and briefly explain it? Simply, is this model worth reporting, or it is fully wrong?

Comment: If you didn't take into account the influence of ID, given what you now know, that would be a huge problem. The fact that you are dealing with it through the random intercept is a sound approach worth reporting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Erik!